# How to iterate array object having multiple array in it?

Tags: java, arrays, spring, object

I've this type of array :

[[{agentId=640214009700, agentMaster=F}],[{agentId=640018009503, partnerId=BLS, agentMaster=F, aepsStatus=F}],[{agentId=640018009503, partnerId=BLS, agentMaster=F}]]

Step 1: using for each loop to iterate the array

for (Object obj : arr) {

System.out.println("obj- " + obj); // this will iterate the loop  and able to get the all array one one, but I'm unable to fetch or iterate this array  -  [{a=1,b=1}]

}

// [{agentId=640214009700, agentMaster=F}],[{agentId=640018009503, partnerId=BLS, agentMaster=F, aepsStatus=F}]
// [{agentId=640018009503, partnerId=BLS, agentMaster=F}]

Step 2: I'm able to get the array one by one but after that I'm not able to get the value or iterate the array inside it.

Please help me out. I've been trying for past 2 days.

Comment: Your array definition is not valid Java. If you have nested arrays, you can add an inner loop inside your outer loop

Comment: Your "array" looks like JSON. Is it?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, let's define the array you provided:

```
    Map<String, Integer> firstMap = new HashMap<>();
    firstMap.put("a", 1);
    firstMap.put("b", 1);

    Map<String, Integer> secondMap = new HashMap<>();
    secondMap.put("c", 1);
    secondMap.put("d", 2);

    Object[][] arr = new Object[][]{
            {firstMap},
            {secondMap}
    };
```

Now, let's use Java streams to iterate over the nested arrays:

```
    Arrays.stream(arr)
            .flatMap(Arrays::stream)
            .filter(Map.class::isInstance)
            .forEach(obj -> {
                Map<String, Integer> map = (Map<String, Integer>) obj;
                map.forEach((key, value) -> System.out.println("Key: " + key + ", Value: " + value));
            });
```

Edited according to your data

```
    Map<?, ?>[][] arr = new Map[][]{
            {new HashMap<String, Object>() {{
                put("agentId", 640214009700L);
                put("agentMaster", "F");
            }}},
            {new HashMap<String, Object>() {{
                put("agentId", 640018009503L);
                put("partnerId", "BLS");
                put("agentMaster", "F");
                put("aepsStatus", "F");
            }}},
            {new HashMap<String, Object>() {{
                put("agentId", 640018009503L);
                put("partnerId", "BLS");
                put("agentMaster", "F");
            }}}
    };

    Arrays.stream(arr)
            .flatMap(Arrays::stream)
            .filter(Objects::nonNull)
            .forEach(obj -> {
                obj.forEach((key, value) -> System.out.println("Key: " + key + ", Value: " + value));
            });
}
```

Comment: Looks I'm already having this type of value   [[{agentId=640214009700, agentMaster=F}],[{agentId=640018009503, partnerId=BLS, agentMaster=F, aepsStatus=F}],[{agentId=640018009503, partnerId=BLS, agentMaster=F}]]
   please help me iterate this value

Comment: Already edited will see if everything is correct